# Android - view loses padding on ListView scroll

Tags: android

I have a `TextView`

```
<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/myshape"
    android:padding="5dp"
    ... />
```

that has the following shape set as the background:

```
<shape>
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFAD6" />
</shape>
```

The `TextView` is displayed within a `ListView`. The problem is that the padding is lost on scroll. When the list view first renders it looks fine:

[image]

When the list is scrolled back and forth the padding is lost:

[image]

What am I missing?

**Edit** Here's the code:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyBean> {

    private Context context;
    private List<MyBean> myBeans;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<MyBean> myBeans) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, myBeans);
        this.context = context;
        this.myBeans = myBeans;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_activity, parent, false);
        }

        MyBean bean = myBeans.get(position);
        setData(row, bean);
        return row;
    }

    private void setData(View layout, MyBean bean) {
        TextView dateHeader = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dateHeader);
        dateHeader.setText(bean.getDate());

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.box);
        textView1.setText("textView 1");

        TextView box = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.box);
        box.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Foo</b><br><small>Bar</small>"));
        // etc..
    }
}


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        setContentView(listView);
        ArrayAdapter<MyBean> arrayAdapter = new MyBeanArrayAdapter(
                this, R.layout.my_activity, R.id.dateHeader, getBeans());

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }

}
```

**Update** After playing around, I found out that this is happening because the text is split over 2 lines (either using `<br>` or `\n`):

```
box.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Foo</b><br><small>Bar</small>"));
box.setText("Foo \n Bar");
```

When I remove `<br>` or `\n`, the `TextView` box maintains its size.

I don't have a solution to this yet however. Open to suggestions.

Comment: what if you put the padding in the shape?

Comment: Tried that. Same result though...

Comment: can you post some more of your code and also mention which devices you've tested this on?

Comment: @MattWolfe added the code. I am not testing this on any hardware, just the AVD at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced similar behavior. It looks like layout params are lost when views a recycled within your list adapter. I have ended up setting layout params inside **getView()** method of my adapter. You may try setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom) in your getView() and see whether it fixes the problem.